# Google Compute Engine won't send emails with links

Tags: email, gmail, google-compute-engine

Recently I moved my site to GCE and now emails are not being sent. I send them using gmail's smtp server, through the port 465.

A simple google search points to [this article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail), in which they say that I must use a third party solution like SendGrid.

The weird thing is, I can send regular emails. I was testing my site and I am able to send a simple email with "Hello world" in the message body. But the moment I add a link (URL address) to the body message, the email is not sent.

Is this an expected behaviour? Is there a work around?

I think it's dumb for Google to not allow sending emails even though its own Gmail servers.

Comment: What kinda links are we talking here? You sure that Gmail isn't the one blocking your messages? If you're sending straight through Gmail servers, chances are GCE has nothing to do with it. That's just an idea though.

Comment: Url's. Either inside a <p> tag or an <a>

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Google Cloud (despite of what they claim) does allow smtp traffic. I added the firewall exception of the port tcp:465 for all IP addresses.

Additionally, emails containing links were being sent to the spam box, but just on my email account. I sent it to another account and it worked just fine.

[Edit]

GCE had **nothing to do** with the links problem. It was the poor design of my email content that caused it to go to the spam folder.

The solution was already there. Open the right firewall ports and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is some confusion here. "*Despite*" of what they say...

Look at their article on [Sending Email from an Instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail) and I quote:

> "Google Compute Engine does not allow outbound connections on ports
>   25, 465, and 587 **but you can still set up your instances to send mail**
>   through ports 587 and 465 using servers provided through partner
>   services, such as SendGrid."

They clearly state that you **CAN** do it.

Also, if you're authenticating with your Google Account to send via `smtp.gmail.com`, you're authenticating with a username and password just like any standard email client would. So why would that not be allowed? You're basically connecting as an email client.

On another note, your issues with links were related to the quality of the message therefore being marked as spam (GCE wasn't causing any problems.) by Gmail, as I suspected in my previous comment. You're mainly using Gmail here, and not really any issues directly related to GCE.

I hope this clarifies things a little.

Comment: The way I see it, Google just doesn't want to have their GCE IPs used for SMTP spamming, abuse and what ever and what not. Considering the fact that they do offer Email hosting and SMTP services, they probably don't want people sending mail straight from GCE to intended recipients which is why they propose using a relay through a service or your own server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for clarifying things I'm not saying explicitly. You are totally right.My only concern is that Google made me believe that my app running on GCE would not be able to have an email client if I didn't use SendGrid. I understand their spam-related concern though, but I don't think it's right to mislead.